# How to use Redmine with AWS SES for email notifications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, redmine

I have installed Redmine 2.2.2 stable from Bitnami AWS EC2 instance. It work nice but i don't know how to make Redmine emails notifications use my AWS SES SMTP sender.

My FQDN (my_fqdn.com) is verified by AWS SES as a Verified Sender.

I've configured my Redmine config/configuration.yml file like :

```
# ==== SMTP server over AWS SES
production:
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      enable_starttls_auto: true
      address: email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
      port: 25
      domain: my_fqdn.com
      authentication: :login
      user_name: smtp_access_key
      password: smtp_secret_key
      openssl_verify_mode: 0
```

NB : Doesn't work even if i remove : openssl_verify_mode: 0

But when i try to send a "test email" from "Email notification", i have an error :

```
An error occurred while sending mail (hostname does not match the server certificate)
```

What "sever certificat" mean here ?

My Redmine instance never send any email...

Is it necessary to install and configure postfix that relay to AWS SES on my server ?

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you need to configure the prod and dev environnement in bottom of the config/configuration.yml file :

```
production:
   ...

development:
   ... (same config as prod for me)
```

and copy paste my config.

On my AWS SES account i need to verify my domain.

And now it's work ! :-)

I hope this will help someone.